# What should I do to solve this error?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I was using JSONParser to obtain results of a search, for that I followed this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

The thing is that, the API I am using gives the results like this:

```
{"response":[50036,{"aid":88131498,"owner_id":61775052,"artist":"Terror Squad","title":"Lean Back (OST Need For Speed Underground 2)","duration":249,"url":"http:\/\/cs4408.vkontakte.ru\/u59557424\/audio\/7f70f58bb9b8.mp3","lyrics_id":"3620730"},{"aid":106963458,"owner_id":-24764574,"artist":"«Dr. Dre ft Eminem, Skylar Grey (Assault Terror)","title":"I Need A Doctor (ASSAULT TERROR DUBSTEP REMIX)»","duration":240,"url":"http:\/\/cs5101.vkontakte.ru\/u79237547\/audio\/12cd12c7f8c2.mp3","lyrics_id":"10876670"}]}
```

My problem comes when I have to parse the first integer (here it is 50036) which is the number of results found.

I don't know how to read that integer.

This is my code:

```
private void instance(String artisttrack){
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    String jsonurl = new String( "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.search?access_token=ACC_TOKEN&api_id=ID&sig=SIG&v=2.0&q=" + artistname + artisttrack + "&count=5");
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonurl);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        response = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            //int results = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_RESULTS));
            String aid = c.getString(TAG_AID);
            String owner_id = c.getString(TAG_OWNER_ID);
            String artist = c.getString(TAG_ARTIST);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String duration = c.getString(TAG_DURATION);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
            String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);
            String lyrics_id = c.getString(TAG_LYRICS_ID);
            Log.e("áaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", url);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The JSONParser.java is like written in the tutorial.

And here 2 lines of the logcat error:

```
W/System.err(10350): org.json.JSONException: Value 50036 at 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err(10350):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
```

Comment: I believe it's a formatting issue. For example, name:number. However 5036 is formed differently, it's 5036:[array items]. On the example given to you the format is very different. Item name:[array items]. This is most likely the issue of your JSon parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON sample is a poor way to organize the results: mixing the number in with the result objects. Is the number supposed to indicate the number of objects in the array or something else?

If you can assume that this number will always be the first element, and according to [this](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=audio.search) then it's supposed to work this way, you can try to read the first value of the array outside the loop:

```
response = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

// from your example, num will be 50036:
num = response.getInt(0);

for (int i = 1; i < response.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);
```

Note that the example in the linked documentation has this number as a string:

```
{"response":
    ["5",
     {"aid":"60830458","owner_id":"6492","artist":"Noname","title":"Bosco",
"duration":"195","url":"http:\/\/cs40.vkontakte.ru\/u06492\/audio\/2ce49d2b88.mp3"},
     {"aid":"59317035","owner_id":"6492","artist":"Mestre Barrao","title":"Sinhazinha",
"duration":"234","url":"http:\/\/cs510.vkontakte.ru\/u2082836\/audio\/
d100f76cb84e.mp3"}]}
```

But `JSONArray.getInt()` will parse the `String` as an `int` for you.

And notice that some of the values in the objects in your array are also numbers, you may want to read those as `int` also:

```
int aid = c.getInt(TAG_AID);
int owner_id = c.getInt(TAG_OWNER_ID);
int duration = c.getInt(TAG_DURATION);
```

Comment: But i have a problem, 50036 is a variable depening on the search... so, i cannot complete num = json.getInt(0); what else could i do? Thanks!

Comment: @BamsBamx the number can be variable, i.e. have different values depending on the search. The code still works: read the number and act on it.

Comment: Thanks again! If i insert this: num = json.getInt(0); i got method org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.string) in org.json.JSONObject cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: @BamsBamx sorry mistake in my code, see edits: use your `response` variable, e.g. `response.getInt(0)`

Comment: Ok, then i got this /System.err(14224): org.json.JSONException: Value 50046 at 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @BamsBamx check the code, looks like you're making a mistake: did you remember to change the `for` loop to start at _1_ instead of _0_: `for (int i = 1; ...` as in my example?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the values you are trying to parse in are not `String` objects, specifically "aid", "owner_id", and "duration".  Use the correct method to retrieve values.  For example:

```
int aid = c.getInt(TAG_AID);
int owner_id = c.getInt(TAG_OWNER_ID);
String artist = c.getString(TAG_ARTIST);
String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
int duration = c.getInt(TAG_DURATION);
```

edit: Another error that I missed is you start your array with 50036.  This is not a JSONObject and cannot be parsed as so.  You can add a conditional statement to check if it's array index 0 to parse the int using `getInt()`, and then parse as JSONObjects for the rest of the array values.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
response = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);
```

into

```
response = (JSONObject)json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);
```

I dont have any experience with JSONObject, but works often with type mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 50036 in quotes like this "50036" .

Comment: 50036 is the result of a variable int so i cannot put that number in quotes